# insert-char completion says no matches, but inserts character anyway?

Tags: completion, unicode, characters, insert, insert-char

I'm using `C-x 8 RET` to insert a Unicode character. I enter the hex value -- for example, `201c` -- and the minibuffer says "no matches". But if I just hit enter, the expected left double quote character “ gets inserted.

OTOH, if I type "left quot" or similar, the completion narrows the choices as expected, and I can use tab to complete LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK as expected.

I'm seeing similar behavior even when I start emacs with "-Q": there, I type "201c", hit tab -- it says no match, but if I hit enter, it inserts the character.

Why is the completion saying there's no matches, but hitting enter successfully finds the character?

Answer (score 1):

You see `No match` when you hit `TAB` because there's no match for the text `201c` using the `completion-styles` you have.

More importantly, `C-x 8 RET` matches character **names**, not code points. But if you hit `RET` to **enter** a code point, then its char is inserted.

See the doc of function `insert-char` (which is bound to `C-x 8 RET`). It says:

> You can specify `CHARACTER` in one of these ways:
>
> - As its Unicode **character name**, e.g. `"LATIN SMALL LETTER A"`.
>   **Completion is available**; if you type a substring of the name
>   preceded by an asterisk `*`, Emacs shows all names which include
>   that substring, not necessarily at the beginning of the name.
> - As a hexadecimal code point, e.g. `263A`.  Note that code points in
>   Emacs are equivalent to Unicode up to `10FFFF` (which is the limit of
>   the Unicode code space).
> - As a code point with a radix specified with `#`, e.g. `#o21430`
>   (octal), `#x2318` (hex), or `#10r8984` (decimal).

Comment: Hrm, it seems you're right. But it's very unintuitive: the completion for me shows the hex code point too, so I expected the completion to look at that. But I guess if the completion really is just looking at the names, then saying there's no match is technically correct...

Comment: If you see the code points also but there's no completion against them then they are likely shown only as *annotations*. (There's no completion against annotations.)